# Custom semi circular progress bar

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Can you help me to create this progress bar effect? I have the background bar and the colored bar. I tried to use ClipRrect but it work better for rect bars, this is a semi circular bar and I can’t get the effect that I want
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNM4i.jpg)

I tried ClipRect, works well but not for semi circular images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a CustomPainter and AnimatedBuilder. Create custom classes, and you can import CircularArchProgressBar anywhere in your app. Keep in mind that the value must always be less than 50 according to the current implementation. You can improve this code to achieve more and beyond.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Circular Arch Progress Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CircularArchProgressBar(value: 10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircularArchProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double value;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final Color fillColor;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  CircularArchProgressBar(
      {required this.value,
      this.strokeWidth = 10.0,
      this.fillColor = Colors.blue,
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.grey});

  @override
  _CircularArchProgressBarState createState() =>
      _CircularArchProgressBarState();
}

class _CircularArchProgressBarState extends State<CircularArchProgressBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: widget.value).animate(_controller);

     _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: CircularArchProgressBarPainter(
              strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
              color: widget.backgroundColor,
              value: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return CustomPaint(
                painter: CircularArchProgressBarPainter(
                  strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
                  color: widget.fillColor,
                  value: _animation.value,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CircularArchProgressBarPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double value;
  final Color color;

  CircularArchProgressBarPainter(
      {required this.strokeWidth, required this.value, required this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final double radius = size.width / 2;
    final double startAngle = math.pi/2;
    final double sweepAngle = 2 * math.pi * (value / 100);

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(radius, radius), radius: radius),
      startAngle, 
      sweepAngle,
      false,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfect! Even the bar images I don't need them any more.